# how to sort json with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a json which is structured like this (called `json` in the complete question)

```
[
    {"ID": "1", "Name": "Harry", "Age": "18"},
    {"ID": "2", "Name": "Ron", "Age": "18"},
    {"ID": "3", "Name": "Hermione", "Age": "18"},
    {"ID": "4", "Name": "Ginny", "Age": "18"},
    {"ID": "5", "Name": "Fred", "Age": "18"},
]
```

In my template I show it like following in my `<b-form-select>` :

```
<b-form-select class="showPointer">
  <option v-for="item in json" :key="item.id">
    ID: {{ item.id}}, Name: {{ item.name}}, Age: {{ item.age}}
  </option>
</b-form-select>
```

Now to my **problem**: I want to `sort` it based on my `name` and I know that I have to put it first into a `computed-function` but I don't know how..

But I want to display it in my `template` like in my example above (ID, than Name, than Age).

Thanks for your help! Thank You!

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need computed for this.

You could sort it immediately after you receive the request response.

Example

```
get(....).then(response=> { 
    this.json = response.sort((a,b) => a.name - b.name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Abregre is right, you don't need computed for this.

But in any case, you can use computed like this:

```
<option v-for="item in sortedJson" :key="item.id">

computed: {
  sortedJson () {
    return this.json.sort((a, b) => a.Name - b.Name)
  }
}
```